# Has anyone implemented DORA metrics on top of the Azure DevOps Services using Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops

We use Azure DevOps Server 2020 (on-prem), but I am fine with answers pertaining to the Services edition.

I wonder if anyone has implemented the DORA metrics with Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines?

We are about to embark on this journey, so I would like to learn of other's experience.

---

My plan of action is to write a scheduled build that would execute REST API to collect pipeline metrics and send them over to Application Insights. The problem is that AppInsights does not have good presentation abilities, so a 3rd party product will have to be used to create nice dashboards.